# Open-source SDK for Tizen

Tags: open-source, software-development, sdk

I'd like to develop a GPL app for a Tizen smartwatch. Unfortunately, its SDK is closed-source, as discussed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131009220540/https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/tizen-sdk-licensing-makes-whole-tizen-not-open-source), so I'd rather avoid using it.

Is there a way to make Tizen watch apps without using its SDK? Any alternative open-source SDKs?

A completely open-source SDK would be ideal, though I would settle for an SDK that allows me to release the app under the GPL v3.